# Arc length when the curve intersect itself

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative, plane-curves

I came a cross a theorem saying that the arc length of a smooth non self-intersecting parametric curve is  given by

$ L= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt(y’^2+x’^2)dx$

Why we specify that the curve should be smooth and not intersecting itself is that means we should split the interval and integrate each loop separately

Also if a particle travelled arround a circle 3 times from t=0 to $t=3\pi$  when we find the arc length is it giving us the whole distance that the particle travelled or it is only the length of the circle once?

Comment: The length of a smooth curve can be defined as above, keep in mind that the length is a characteristic of the curve not the range of the curve. The author may have other reasons to specify non intersecting.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not smooth, the derivatives are undefined.

If it is self-intersecting, you can run around the loop forever.